# Use Visual Studio Installer to write into the PATH env

Tags: visual-studio, path, windows-installer

I am working on the installer for a program and I am trying to access the executable, independent of the installation location.

I thought one way to do that is by writing into the PATH env (by writing into the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment) but when the program gets uninstalled the entire PATH gets deleted.

I was looking into CustomActions, but it's not really clear to me how I can write into the PATH env that way.

Do you have any suggestions? DO you know any other way?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it *really* necessary to modify the path? There are normally ways around like putting dll dependencies in the same dir as the executable or starting the program via a batch file which adds to the PATH (temporarily)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904053/how-to-add-application-folder-to-path-after-installation-vs-setup-project